# Can I use only WebP images with a WordPress site and prevent the CMS from reformatting and resizing them?

Tags: seo, wordpress, images, google-image-search

What do you guys thing, should one make a website using only webP images? Could it be a big mistake? It is an image heavy website.

Would WebP work with with WordPress?  I'm not sure that it matters when WordPress just reformats and resizes just about anything I upload.

Answer (score 2):

WebP images load faster than JPG and PNG images, so it is a good progressive enhancement, particularly if your site is image heavy.

But if by "only" WebP you mean there would not be a JPG or PNG alternative, I don't think that is a good idea because your images won't be available to people on Internet Explorer, which doesn't support WebP right now.

With updates like this its a good idea to look at how people are accessing your site. In analytics, are people typically using mobile or desktop, and what kind of browsers do they tend to use.

As far as whether WebP is possible in Wordpress, yes there are WP plugins set up for this.

Comment: CanIUse says that about [5% of users don't support webP](https://caniuse.com/webp).  The biggest group is older versions of Safari which account for about 4% of users.

Comment: I recommended Shortpixel in another thread. Personally I think these belong in the WordPress site because they are theme and plugin specific questions.